# Trouble with installion of zend framework 2 on wamp 2.5

Tags: php, powershell, zend-framework, wampserver

So becaue I do not have a clue whats wrong I give you full information about what I did before and all determining factors. (The Problem is specified at the bottom)

1. wamp was already installed. My localhost path is:

   ```
    F:\Program Files\wamp\www
   ```

   So the Space could lead to a fail somewhere.
2. Downloaded SendSkeletonApplication from GitHub (because Tut. told me to) and extract it to my created folder zf2. So its everything in:

   ```
     F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2
   ```

   and only that you now I extract it right here is the path to the public folder:

   ```
      F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2\public
   ```
3. Downloaded Composer-Setup.exe from:

   ```
      https://getcomposer.org/download/
   ```
4. enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini so here is the line (without semicolon):

   ```
     extension=php_openssl.dll
   ```
5. open Windows PowerShell and do following things:

   ```
   going to this directory:
   PS F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2> composer self-update
   PS F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2> composer install
   ```

   both worked so I checked php -v:

   ```
   PS F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2> php -v
   PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:58) 
   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
   Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
           with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
   ```
6. Now it gets confused because of different Tuts. I did following things to:

   ```
   Open Windows System -> Advanced system settings -> Environmental Variables -> System variables -> Path -> Edit
   Edit the php5.5.15 and zf2 (Composer was already there):
   ;F:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2
   ```
7. Open and Editing:

   ```
    F:\Program Files\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf
    uncomment: Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
    so the line now looks like (without #):
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```
8. Well I followed one tutorial but it did not worked so I did following thinks not in the exact order:

   ```
   Editing following things to 
   F:\Program Files\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf
   and also to
   F:\Program Files\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf


   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.zf2.com
   DocumentRoot "F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2\public"
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
   <Directory "F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2\public">
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   </IfModule>
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "F:\Program Files\wamp\www"
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
   <Directory "F:\Program Files\wamp\www">
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
9. Going to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add this code:

   ```
    127.0.0.1  dev.zf2.com
   ```

So now if I am going to dev.zf2.com I get to localhost of wamp, so there is no Skeleton Applications. I tried to open the public folder in zf2 because there is a index.php:

```
 http://localhost/zf2/public
```

but it says: Internal Server Error.

So what is wrong? Do I installed it right?

Also, why is there no library in zf2 ?

And what are the next steps to start with zend ?

Comment: Just to be sure, after you modified the vhost config, did you restart the Apache server/service?  Those changes don't take effect until you reload the config or restart Apache.

Comment: No I did not, but now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used wamp, however, for step 8, your vhosts probably want to look more like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.zf2.com
    DocumentRoot "F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2\public"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "F:\Program Files\wamp\www\zf2\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "F:\Program Files\wamp\www"
    <Directory "F:\Program Files\wamp\www">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You don't need them in both `httpd.conf` and `httpd-vhosts.conf` (although that isn't likely to cause a problem). Just do one or the other to avoid confusion.

You have a random `</IfModule>` in your example, and the `Order allow,deny` stuff changed a bit in Apache 2.4 (which you appear to be using - the tutorial you're following may have been correct for the Apache version at the time). These two things are likely to be why you're getting an internal server error.

You have to restart Apache after making configuration changes or they won't have any effect (as per drew010's comment).

You want to be viewing `http://dev.zf2.com` in your browser, not localhost.

If it still doesn't work after that:

- If you are still getting 'Internal Server Error', you need to figure out where the Apache error logs are, as each server error should have a corresponding log entry which will give you some clue as to the cause.
- You've not mentioned anything about mod_rewrite - I don't know if this is something that's enabled by default in wamp, but if not, that would be an issue. If the error log has something about not recognising 'RewriteEngine', then enabling mod_rewrite should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the </IfModule> and deleted the two Virtualhost parts from httpd.conf. I forgot that I actually  changed mod_rewrite, so there is no # anymore. However, now it worked. Thanks for your help...